# Собрать список друзей произвольного пользователя, которые ставят "Мне нравится"

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Подскажите как лучше собрать список друзей произвольного пользователя, которые поставили лайк на его фотографиях (`photo type=profile`)

Интересует конкретно алгоритм действий с методами vk api и возможностями php.

P.S. (Решение с `friends.only=1` не подходит, т.к. применятся задуманное должно к любому произвольному пользователю)

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: Я еще не пробовал, но планирую писать код который бы собирал базу всех друзей
всех фотографий
после чего прогонял эту базу друзей
через каждую фотографию и записывал в массив кто и сколько лайков оставил.  Но возможно есть способ проще?

Comment: Ну да, брать друга и проверять лайки, не знаю даже, как ещё. Попробуйте так, если что, всегда можно переписать.

Comment: Ну или каждую фотографию через друзей, как вы сказали